# Accessing Drupal.settings outside of attach function

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm trying to make some of my Javascript in a Drupal 7 module a bit more modular, as I want to access a function inside `Drupal.behaviors.attach()` from another JS file. So first of all I need to move some variable declarations, and then the functions, outside of the attach function and hopefully access the variables from inside it with this.vars.myVariable - I'll try and explain a bit further with some slightly dummified code...

Initial, working code:

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myModule_someJS = {

    attach: function(context, settings) {

      var initial_page = Drupal.settings.myModule.initial_page;
      console.log(initial_page); // returns a value

    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myModule_someJS = {

    vars: {
      initial_page : Drupal.settings.myModule.initial_page
      // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'initial_page' of undefined 
    },

    attach: function(context, settings) {

      console.log(this.vars.initial_page);

    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

It seems that outside of the scope of the attach function, `Drupal.settings` doesn't exist. Is there any way I can access these settings (defined in my .module file) from anywhere within behaviors.myModule_someJS ?

Thanks! Matt

Comment: I don't see where your error is, but `Drupal.settings` is definitely available outside the scope of the attach function. Just open FireBug console on a Drupal 7 site and type `Drupal.settings` - you will see that the object exists.

Comment: Unless anyone knows how I can access a function *within* the attach function from a separate javascript file? Because that's what I'm essentially trying to do, but it seems impossible, unless I'm just an idiot...

Comment: @AliceHeaton, thanks for your response! If I type `Drupal.settings.myModule.initial_page` into the console it gives my answer, but outside of the attach it doesn't seem to...

Comment: To make a function visible outside the scope, just make an assignment to an attribute of window, eg. window.myfunction = myfunction. Not recommended and may cause all sorts of new scoping issues, mind.

Comment: Thanks guys, worked it out myself. Until attach() is called, Drupal.settings doesn't contain my custom variables. I'll answer my own question later (not enough rep to do it before 8 hours! Bah..)

Comment: @MattFletcher - where do you call `drupal_add_js` in your server side code ? It is possible the problem comes from there. I have a module which calls it in `hook_init`, and my settings are available before `attach` is called.

Comment: Within hook_form, which is a menu page callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out myself.

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myModule_someJS = {

    anotherFunction: function() {
      console.log(this.vars.initial_page);
    },

    attach: function(context, settings) {

      this.vars = {
        initial_page  : Drupal.settings.myModule.initial_page
      }

      this.anotherFunction();

    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Drupal.settings won't contain the custom stuff sent through from my module *until* the attach function is called, so therefore every settings variable can only be called inside attach()

(and from Alice's comments above, it may be a matter of drupal_add_js being called from within the page rather than in the init() hook)